# Dask.array conversion of a pointwise array operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

Is it feasible to "daskify" a pointwise function written in terms of general numpy operations  ?

Case example + Partial Solution:
For example, see here : https://github.com/SciTools/iris/pull/2964

The point of that is that we want to apply a generalised array operation from another library, but it can only operate on actual numpy arrays.
Whereas we want it to operate on an existing dask array in this operation, and produce a lazy result for which sub-arrays can be efficiently computed.
Which is why it is using `da.from_array` ...

Alternatives:
You could instead use deferred, but if you do it must evaluate the whole of the argument every time, even if the result is sub-indexed.

Or you could use frompyfunc
http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.frompyfunc
But that uses a scalar function, not an array function.
Which is inefficient, especially as it returns an array of objects rather than numbers.

Remaining Problem:
In the above partial solution, the missing piece is the ability to "see through" the opaque point-calculation wrapper, so its dask arguments are visible to the whole graph.
? Perhaps there is a way in Dask to expose the `dask_array` argument which is currently hidden in this `from_array(ArraylikeWrapper(dask_array))` construction ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking here.  The example you point to is just a PR without any examples.  I've given an answer, but I don't understand your situation well enough to know if it's appropriate.

Comment: I think this is totally fixed, including the "remaining problem" so that is a righteous solution.

Comment: >  not entirely clear to me what you're asking ...
**To Clarify**
The original problem is to take an existing pointwise (aka elementwise) operation on numpy arrays and produce an equivalent operation on Dask arrays, such that : (a) it passes data in chunks as  numpy arrays to the original function, (b) it's usage of the argument is fully optimised in terms of sub-array calculations and sharing with other parts of a graph

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [da.map_blocks](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks)?

```
x = x.map_blocks(func)
```

Dask also supports NumPy ufuncs with the `__array_ufunc__` protocol if you're able to create those (though `map_blocks` is likely easier).

Comment: No, I had heard of it but thought it passed dask items into the function.
On quick try, that may work
-- watch this space ...

Comment: Thanks, that is the real thing !